# Permission Error when accessing Python file

Tags: permissions, python, python3

I am receiving this error and am unable to address it. I don't understand how I don't have permission to these files in the python3.6 directory.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have tried to change the permissions on this file with chmod, but I received the "Operation not permitted" error and I am unsure of how to address this.

I recently installed, then uninstalled, anaconda. Could this have messed with my python Path/permissions?

The command "which python" outputs /usr/bin/python
The command "which python3.6" outputs /usr/bin/python3.6

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the `python` binary in Anaconda? If you are, then it shouldn't be trying to write to /usr/local/lib/python3.6. Add the output of `which python` and `which python3.6` to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am using the python binary in anaconda, but I don't think so since `which python` outputs `/usr/bin/python` and `which python3.6` outputs `/usr/bin/python3.6`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a file permission error - see the line that triggered the fault:

```
sock.connect(sa)
```

This is a network connection attempt. Either your local port number is less than 1024 (so it's a privileged port requiring root permissions) or there's something like SELinux getting involved.